# How center a prepend loading div?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).on('facetwp-refresh', function() {
        $('.facetwp-template').prepend('<div class="is-loading">Loading...</div>');
    });
    $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {
        $('.facetwp-template .is-loading').remove();
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>

<style>
    .is-loading{
   position: relative;
     width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    align-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;    
    color: white;   
    }   
    
</style>
```

I have a lot of trouble trying to center my `.is-loading` div inside `.facetwp-template` I want it to always be in the center of the content `.facetwp-template`

if someone can simulate such a situation
`.facetwp-template` can be any div and insert a loading div inside and show me what I missed and didn't understand.

maybe even add an ovelay effect to see the "white" loading text
and if you're crazy enough
maybe also insert a slightly exotic loading animation like a spinning icon?

**what I got**
[image]

**what I want**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `display: flex;` or `display: inline-flex;` to your `.is-loading` class. Only then you can apply other flex-related attributes to your class.
Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enginustun/p32zbkwn/2/

You can try following style;

```
.is-loading {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make position absolute and then adjust your div position on the screen. Something like:

```
<style>
    .is-loading{

   position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    align-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;    
    color: white;   
    }   
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it absoulte and give top, left 50% to place it center of the screen.
Then translate by -50%.

```css
  .is-loading{
    position: absoulte;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;    
    color: white;   
    }
```